# rack-pjax not working, no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax

I tried to get [rack-pjax](https://github.com/eval/rack-pjax) working on my rails app according to [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax), but I have noticed no change, nor any errors. Here are the pertinent files:

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'pg'
gem 'koala', '~> 1.7.0rc1'
gem 'rack-pjax'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fancybox-rails'

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

config/application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))

end

module Prestongunderson
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Pjax

    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    config.assets.enabled = true

    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require fancybox
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require_tree .
```

app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
    jQuery ->
        $("a.fancybox").fancybox()
    jQuery ->
      $('.local-nav a').pjax('[data-pjax-container]')
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/subscribe' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/soundcloud' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/tweet-stream' %>
    <body>

        <div data-pjax-container>
            <%= yield %>
        </div>

        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/google_analytics' %>
    </body>
</html>
```

app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<header>
  ...
    <ul>
        <% ["Home", "Bio", "Gallery", "Music", "Tour", "Videos", "Contact"].each do |page| %>
            <li><%= link_to( page.upcase, @title == page ? "#" : "/#{page.downcase}", class: "local-nav") %></li>
        <% end %>
    ...
  </ul>
  ...
</header>
```

Is it possible for me to have conflicting code somewhere? Are there some other dependencies I'm missing?

## Edit

This is supposed to use Ajax to load only the data in the `div` with the `data-pjax-container` on a link request. Instead, it loads the entire page. I test this by playing a song in the media player I have in a side bar, rendered in layout `_soundcloud.html.erb`, outside of the yeild. When clicking a link set up with pjax, it should only update the single `div`, but it loads a whole new page, and stops the music.

Comment: Please share what you're expecting and what's happening.

Comment: Your Gemfile is missing `pjax_rails`???

Comment: @vinodadhikary, `rake-pjax` is also an alternative.

Comment: @BillyChan did you mean `rack-pjax`?

Comment: @JShoe I guess so, I was googling `rake-pjax` until I saw your comment lol.

Comment: ah, yes, guys, rack-pjax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `jquery-pjax` API that you use seems to be outdated now. According to the docs, this line

```
$('a.local-nav').pjax('[data-pjax-container]')
```

should be

```
$(document).pjax('a.local-nav', '[data-pjax-container]')
```

Btw, you should use `a.local-nav` selector instead of `.local-nav a` if you set `local-nav` class to the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar experience though using `pjax-rails`, but the reason should be the same on JS side.

A very possible reason is it takes a bit long for your development server to response. Pjax can't wait so long by default, so it falls back to normal HTTP request.

The solution is to add time out option on JS

```
$('.local-nav a').pjax('[data-pjax-container]', {timeout: 2000})
```

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. I even ramped the time up to 6000. It starts the render of the new page fairly quickly, it doesn't seem to even try to use `pjax`.

Answer (score 0):

pjax breaks when redirect involved in request cycle. Check it aswel.